# Download file from directory when using MVC on PHP

Tags: php, file, model-view-controller, download

So, i've developed a website using MVC on PHP and i have inside the root directory a folder called 'uploads'. Inside my HTML, i have a few anchor tags to download the files from inside that uploads folder. I tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
<a download href="uploads/file_name.ext"> Download </a>
```

How should i do that?

Comment: Maybe try just `<a href="uploads/file_name.ext">Download</a>` (remove `download` between `a` &  `href`)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, if i remove the 'download' term, it just redirects me to a non-existing page.

Comment: Then `uploads/file_name.ext` is incorrect. You need the actual path of the file there. Also, if you keep `download` in there what happens? You never said.

Comment: I was trying to download a PDF file, then a changed to a PNG image file and it worked. I guess the problem is the PDF file

Answer (score 0):

First, create a php script that get requested file and download file with GET Request.

For example , convert your request from uploads/file_name.ext to download.php?file=file_name.ext.
Then,use php code below;

```
$file_url = "uploads/".$_GET["file"];
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
exit;
```

After you create your download script , final html code will be like below

```
<a href="download.php?file=file_name.ext"> Download </a>
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['file']) )
{
$filename = $_REQUEST['file'];

header("Content-type:application/txt");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='$filename'");
 }
else
{
        // error goes here
}
?>

<a download href="uploads/file_name.txt"> Download </a>
```